# Parsing Variable? Rechecking Variable? Unsure Title

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I'm not sure what this is called, parsing? Recheck variable?... I'll edit title when I know!

Something simple like this;

```
var a = b;
var c = d;
var bd = 'hello!';
var e = a + c;

alert(e);
// Want to alert 'Hello!'
```

In my actual script var b is set on a click event which makes var c equal something like this `Staff_Member_TimMarshall` whereas `a = Staff_Member_` and the onclick sets `b = TimMarshall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is invalid to have variable names only be numbers.

Second, you can use `eval` for this

```js
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';
var ab = 'hello!';
var c = a + b;

console.log(eval(c));
```

On a final note, take the use of `eval` with caution.

See [When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

There is usually a way to avoid using `eval` and if you give more info in your question, we can attempt a better `eval`-less solution.

Comment: I would not recommend using `eval` for just about anything, especially for a new JS developer.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!

Comment: @dgrundel, right, I included a final note in my answer. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Ah, awesome! You must have been updating your answer when I wrote that. :)

Answer (score 1):

`12` isn't a valid variable name in JS, I believe. Consider putting this into an object:

```
var obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    '12': 'hello!'
};

alert(obj[ '' + obj['a'] + obj['b'] ]);
```

You also have an issue because `a + b === 3`, not `12`, unless you're doing a string concatenation. So you have to do `'' + 1 + 2` to get the string `12`.